# Application, improve performance of touch events

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, touch, multi-touch

Basically, I have an application witch is 8000px by 8000px.  We can zoom in to view a specific part, example on the radio, or we can zoom out to view everything.

Each part of the car is a control that we can manipulate with fingers, on a dual touch or multitouch monitor.

My problem is: for manipulating a control, for example the Volume button, the user needs to move the mouse exactly like in real life, so with a circular movement. 
With the mouse everything is perfect, it responds instantly without any delay. I use the OnMouseLeftButtonDown, OnMouseMove, etc.
With the touch, it seems to be very difficult for the computer to get the touch position and there is a huge lag, especially when the user move 2 different button with 2 fingers at the same time. I use the OnTouchDown, OnTouchMove, etc...

The only difference between the mouse and the touch is when we need to get the position, with the Mouse I use: (e is a MouseButtonEventArgs)

```
Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
```

With the Touch I use: (e is a TouchEventArgs)

```
Point currentPosition = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;
```

Everything after this is the same.

I don't know if it's because I have too many control in the my application (over 5000 that we can manipulate, but when we zoom in on only 2 control it's the same thing) or because it is really difficult for the computer to get the position from a touch event....

Can someone help me with this? I need to find a solution to eliminate the lag.

I use Visual Studio 2010, Blend 4, .NET 4.0
Windows 7 64-bit
7 Gb RAM
Xeon 2.13 Ghz, 2 core, 8 thread
Screen: ELO technology, in a NEC 2490WUXi2 screen

Comment: If everything works well with the mouse and you do not have any delays manipulating the controls, then I would say the culprit is the touch device driver. I think it is not able to keep up with the finger speed and therefore introducing the lag you are noticing. I have seen this issue in certain touch hardware and I have used other touch hardware with perfect responsiveness, so I would confidently say that the issue has nothing to do with WPF or touch itself, it is simply the way the driver is implemented for your touch device.

Comment: I suggest that you would try and use the Microsoft Touch Simulator that comes with the Microsoft Surface SDK.

It works with mouse of course, in that sense, as Murven mentioned, if there is no lagging in receiving and responding to the touch events using the simulator, then the lagging is originating from the multi-touch drivers

Comment: What's the frequency of the OnTouchMove event vs. OnMouseMove? In other words, is OnTouchMove being triggered 1,000 times per second, while OnMouseMove maybe 10 times per second?

Comment: Is it possible the touch hardware is configured for compatibility with double-touch (like iPhone?). That would cause weird delays before reporting an event, while the touch interface tries to determine if a touch is truly standalone or is really just the first part of a gesture. If there is such a configuration option anywhere (most likely in the touch interface driver), try turning it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Take a look at this post.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/756a2ccf-6cf1-4e4a-a101-30b6f3d9c2c9/#ed51226a-6319-49f8-be45-cf5ff48d56bb

Or

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692286/WPF-and-multi-touch

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782456/wpf-touch-event-fires-with-delay

Pls upvote this Bug!

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to say why you have such an issue - may be OnTouchMove is triggered more often than MouseMove and you should create some additional processing to smooth the touch positions data.
I'd try to comment all the code under the 
Point currentPosition = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;

and look at the performance.

Another approach is to count how much OnTouchMove is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the touch device, try another one to see if the lag is still there.

Comment: why do you not let Murven get the accepted answer. this is what he already said in a comment.

Comment: he did not write an answer, I cannot